# Use MVC 4 style scaffolding in VS 2015 Update 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I am updating a few year old website which was originally built with MVC4 (VS2012 perhaps).  I am pretty sure after update 3 when I add a new view using scaffolding I now get the MVC5 style views using Bootstrap, etc.  This site doesn't use bootstrap and there are no plans to add it at this time.  Is there a way to reference the old style scaffolding template so I don't need to build (or rebuild) the view pages by hand after they created?

Currently using VS2015 Update 3

It appears that nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc is running 5.2.3.  Is this the reason I am getting MVC 5 scaffolding templates?

Comment: You are always free to edit the views generated by the scaffolding. Just delete what you don't need !

Comment: Thank you @Shyju I realize this, just trying to avoid this as this is the whole reason for using scaffolding in the first place, so you don't need to roll all your pages from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Scaffolding uses Code Templates, but only to define the Create, List, Edit, Details,Delete and Empty Views. It means that the css are inherited from your _Layout.cshtml. Just remove the bootstrap reference from that and it should work. If you want to customize your Scaffolding layouts, just change the Code Template:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML

More info:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  So basically there is no way to get those old templates back and use them instead?  I guess I will be customizing templates

Comment: I never try to "rollback" to a previous version or something like this. Did you try to customize the CodeTemplates directly and see if it works for you?

Comment: It does seem that is my best option.  Since this site is in maintenance mode and I haven't added a view in 8 months, I will only do this if many views need to be added.  Thanks for the guidance.